# How to refresh activity only in certain cases?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

My problem is, that I want to reload (server request, refresh, etc.) my current activity automatically ONLY when:

**1.-**  the app goes to the background (RECENT_APPS or HOME button clicked), and then opened again (because now it will remain alive in the background, and when I start it again, it just goes to the foreground automatically instead of restarting).

OR

**2.-** the app is in the foreground, and the user locks the screen, and unlocks it again later.

I tried this approach:

```java
Boolean refreshScreenOnResume=false;

onStop(){
    refreshScreenOnResume=true;
}

onResume(){
    if(refreshScreenOnResume){
        refreshScreen();
        refreshScreenOnResume=false;
    }   
}
```

The only problem is that it will set the flag TRUE in onStop() even if a start a new activity, which I don't want.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. It definitely handles your first scenario. I forget whether it handles the second scenario, though in principle it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onRestart()` which is the Activity Lifecycle Method.

[onRestart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()) is called after your activity has been stopped, prior to it being started again.
Always followed by onStart()

In your case:

**Kotlin**

```
    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        refreshScreen()
    }
```

**Java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        refreshScreen();
    }
```